Глагольная приставка "с" versus глагольная приставка "со"
I often wonder if I should form the perfective with "со" or "с" when the imperfective begins with two consonants. We have спрятать, сглодать, сплести, сгнить.. but соврать, солгать, согреть, сорвать, соткать, сохранить, сотворить, созреть... Is there any rule?

Sorry for a useless comment, but I've never seen an exact list. Most of them are intuitive when you see them - as срвать would be hard to say. But there are definitely some that aren't really a case of avoiding consonant clusters. E.g. согреть. Why does this have an extra vowel, when сгрести doesn't? It's not that that combination is unpronounceable as such. I hope you get better replies on this, but Russian sources are mainly focused on setting out for Russian children when to write с- and when to write з-, as со- will have an intuitive spelling for native children.

I seen somewhere complex rules about prefixes "с-" and "со-" but I never seen someone actually used them, so its easier just to remember which is you should use. I like idea from comment above that's its most of all depends on difficulty how to say it. Also i can append that сотворить and створить are both easy to say and actually correct spelling.

Etymologically, the prefix was съ (< Proto-Slavic *sъn). The rule, if it's of any help, is the usual rule that makes the etymological reduced vowels (ъ in this case) fall or clarify (become the full-length vowel о):

The reduced in a strong position (under stress or before a weak reduced) clarified (became full-length vowels)
The reduced in a weak position (before a full-length vowel, a stressed vowel or a reduced in a strong position) fell (stopped being pronounced).

So, there's no mechanical rule, and you have to know the word's etymology.
In the majority of cases:

If the consonant cluster etymologically had a reduced vowel in between the consonants, the prefix is со-. Usually, an etymological reduced manifests itself as a fleeting vowel: сорвать/срывать < *rъvati, солгать/ложный < *lъžь etc. But some words (e.g. соткать < *tъkati) don't have any obvious cognates with a fleeting vowel.

If the consonant cluster didn't have a vowel inside of it, the prefix is с-. Due to the law of rising sonority, most of such clusters are plosives (п, т, к, х and their voiced counterparts) followed by sonorants (л, м, н, р), as you can see in your own examples, but there are numerous exceptions.


A major class of exceptions for this rule is caused by the fact that the Proto-Slavic *sъn gave in fact two reflexes: съ- and сѫ- (a nasal vowel, only preserved to some extent in Polish and other Lechitic languages).
The usual reflex of this vowel in modern Russian is у, but in this particular prefix, due to the Church Slavonic influence, it gives sometimes со-: соцветие, сокровище, сопряжение, sometimes both су- and со-: сомнение, согласие, сопротивление etc., with сумнение, сугласие, супротивление being their dialectal variants.
Some words are cognates formed with both prefixes: сопряжение/спряжение, сокрыть/скрыть, содвинуть/сдвинуть etc.
The prefix су- is not productive in Russian anymore. Some of these words do retain the expected reflex: сугроб, супруг, сумрак etc, but the prefix is not usually analyzed as such and is considered a part of the root.

It is a very valuable answer, thank you very much! Something is unclear to me: you wrote "the prefix was съ" and then " major class of exceptions for this rule is caused by the fact that the Proto-Slavic *sъn gave in fact two reflexes: съ- and сѫ-". So, I didn't understand if all the preverbs were always "съ" and then you generalize the discourse speaking about *sъn (but not as a preverb), or if you should rather write "the prefix was съ or сѫ-

Thus I didn't get if содвинуть/сдвинуть is an example of a derivation from сѫ- ; I wanted to find this information but ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/содвинуть doesn't provide it - do you have resources to recommend?

@Bruno: The original Proto-Slavic suffix was *sъn, cognate either to Greek syn or to Latin sim. n was a sonorous consonant and almost no other consonant could follow it in the same syllable, so it had to be adjusted somehow to be used as a prefix or a proclitical preposition. There were three ways to adjust it: very rare rebracketing (снедать < *sъn ědati, снимать < *sъn jьmati, с ним < *sъn jьmъ); omission (с горы < *sъn gory); and nasalization (сосед/cусед < сѫсѣдъ < *sǫsědъ < *sъn sědъ). The latter happened by analogy with the same change in the roots.

@Bruno: the nasalization happened much more rarely than the omission, so the usual reflex or the prefix or preposition (there was no significant distinction between the two) was съ-, with an occasional сѫ-. I feel like this might have something to do with being a pre-verb preposition (I can't think of a single native Russian verb in су-, as opposed to nouns), but don't have anything to back it up. The fact that содвинуть is a Slavonicism is also obvious to me, but I can't find a reference either, sorry about that.

Thank you again! I have a related question. Following your explanation about сосед, do we have that the со of состричь has derived as follows: со < сѫ < *sǫ < *sъn? Then, how can we explain остричь? Do we have остричь < состричь? Did остричь appear more recently as a simplification of состричь?

@Bruno: сѫ- always means "with", never "from". The prefixes in состричь and остричь are different, the second one being a variant of об- ("around"). Compare сорвать / оборвать, собрать / обобрать etc.

You can be sure only in the following.
Always use co- before c+ a consonant and з+a consonant
Стричь — состричь,
Зреть — созреть
